# What are the standard options for generating printable documentation for an R package?

Tags: r, documentation

When I look at documentation for R packages, it often comes in a PDF document like this:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf

Does that document have a name?

Normally I find these documents by searching on the web, but I wonder if I can also produce them using some R command like `library(help=...)` or `vignette(...)`. However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23504350/5087283) makes it sound somewhat complicated, like I have to compile the package myself and run `R CMD Rd2pdf`, is that correct?

Also, as a prospective package author, I could imagine having this PDF document serve as the primary documentation for my package. The only obstacle is that when I read these documents, the documented functions always seem to appear in alphabetical order. Is there a way to put the most important functions first, so that the document can be read straight through (rather than just as a reference)? Or is there another documentation format which will let me document things in a certain order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference manual is just a collection of the help pages.  They should be written as reference material, which is probably not the first place a user should look for documentation, if that's what you mean by "primary documentation".

The first place users should look is for a vignette which provides an overview of the package.  It can be displayed in HTML or PDF (it's up to the package author to choose).  Since it is free-form, you can document things in a logical order, you aren't restricted to the alphabetical order of the reference manual.

It's also optional, and I use it as a measure of quality of a package that I'm investigating:  if they don't have such a vignette, the authors don't really care about providing good documentation.

Comment: Thank you. Is there another documentation format which will let me document things in a certain order? Or is the function documentation always going to come out alphabetized? And is `R CMD Rd2pdf` how we generate the reference manual?

Comment: The reference manual is alphabetized according to the `\name` field in each file; that will be displayed to users, but isn't forced to have any other connection to the contents of the file.  The `lattice` package uses this to put things in a particular order.  Yes, use `R CMD Rd2pdf` to build it.

Comment: Thank you - interesting about the `lattice` package.